# MySQL count matching words

Tags: sql, mysql, database

How to query to get count of matching words in a field, specifically in MySQL.
simply i need to get how many times a "search terms"appear in the field value.

for example, the value is "one two one onetwo" so when i search for word "one" it should give me 3

is it possible? because currently i just extract the value out of database and do the counting with server side language.

Thank you

Comment: Can you better describe what you want?  Preferably with examples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function to be used directly within SQL, in order to do it all in one step.

Here is [a function which I found on the MySQL website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) :

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS substrCount||
CREATE FUNCTION substrCount(s VARCHAR(255), ss VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE count TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE offset TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET s = NULL;

SET count = 0;
SET offset = 1;

REPEAT
IF NOT ISNULL(s) AND offset > 0 THEN
SET offset = LOCATE(ss, s, offset);
IF offset > 0 THEN
SET count = count + 1;
SET offset = offset + 1;
END IF;
END IF;
UNTIL ISNULL(s) OR offset = 0 END REPEAT;

RETURN count;
END;

||

delimiter ;
```

You should use it like this :

```
SELECT substrCount('one two one onetwo', 'one') `count`; // Returns 3
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking to find a query that, given a list of words, returns the number of matching words in a database field?

eg:

Database table has

```
ID    Terms
1     cat, dog, bird, horse
```

then running a check on the words "cat, horse" returns 2?

If so, I suggest you do your checking *outside* of SQL, in whatever language you're doing the rest of your processing in. SQL isn't designed for this level of processing.

You could *possibly* use a stored procedure to cycle through what words you're needing to check, but I doubt it would be efficient or highly effective.

Of course, if I'm misinterpreting your request, I could be all wrong =)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you do that outside SQL, no matter the engine, Regular Expressions are more suited for that than SQL Language. You could probably do that with a view or something but as I said, there are more proper ways to do it like the string manipulation class/object/function from your language or regular expressions.

Comment: yeah that was what i did, but it doubling the loop, and since the table contain hundreds record it cost a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to search for one term at a time, a function which does something like

```
select (len(field)-len(replace,find,''))/len(find)
```

would work in sql server, but I'm not sure about MySQL. You'd also need to take care of the special case `len(find) = 0`.